# Is there a way to configure TLU to update automatically without entering system password?

Tags: texlive-2018, tex-live-utility

I would like to be able to configure or if needed setup a cron job for the packages to be updated weekly without me having to click on 'update all packages' and then put in my password. I've search the web for this, but cannot find the answer. Is it possible?

Comment: TeX Live comes with a command line utility (`tlmgr`). Running `tlmgr update --all --self` will update your system. If you want to run it as a cron job, you might have to run it as a user with sufficient privileges, depending on your OS.

Comment: I have added in my `/etc/anacrontab` the entry `1       5       texlive.daily   tlmgr update --self --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed`

Comment: This might not be a super good idea. (1) updates only run for about 10 months, (2) never a good idea to update near the end on an important deadline.

Comment: Most common method is use wget with a repo that does not require passwords there are many sources of TL & if your call to a local repo requires password you could simply use another or switch protocols between ftp &/ http. I have not tested personally & if it is  chron that needs permission then you need to find an alternative trigger based on other tasks e.g. a weekly backup script etc. As pointed out by daleif using some repos could have annual cycle and W32tex is 2019 so watch out for compatibility Thus a good case for backup files to be overwritten so you can roll-back at least one update